# VirtualBox VERR_CR_X509_CPV_NOT_VALID_AT_TIME

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I recently started to get a strange error when trying to open any VM on VirtualBox on my Windows 10 Insider Preview 16299.15 (rs3_release) host (emphasis mine):

> 3110.440: VirtualBox.exe: timestamp 0x5a15a474 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
>
> 3110.440: '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe' has no imports
>
> 3110.440: \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll: **VERR_CR_X509_CPV_NOT_VALID_AT_TIME** for 0x9884907b; retrying against current time: 0x5a2e53e1.
>
> 3110.440: Error (rc=-23033):
>
> 3110.440: supHardenedWinVerifyProcess failed with Unknown Status -23033 (0xffffa607): Certificate is not valid (ValidTime=2017-12-11T09:46:09.000000000Z **Validity=[2017-03-23T18:24:49.000000000Z...2017-12-04T18:24:49.000000000Z]**): \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll

I updated (to 5.2.2) and even reinstalled, and people suggested, but to no avail. It seems that some kind of certificate expired, but I don't know how to find it (where is \Device??) nor how to update it.

I tried changing the system date to a past date within the validity period and it worked, but of course that's a temporary solution (literally haha), as other stuff break down if I do so, and I'd like to know how to update the date in this eerie certificate.

Comment: Why are you still running a 2 month old build of RS4.  That particular build isn’t considered to be an Insider Preview build by the way

Comment: @Ramhound about the name, I just copied from the Update Control Panel, as is. About the outdated version, I will try to update. I'm in inside preview but didn't update in a while because of low disk space (I have a 80 GB SSD and that fat Windows eats it all up). But I try to make some backups and see if a windows update help.

Comment: If you were Insider Preview you wouldn’t be running 16299.15

Comment: @Ramhound what I know is, I have this exact version, with this exact name, that I copy-pasted from the panel (I have no knowledge of windows versions); I signed in for Insider Preview; and I updated regularly at the time, but I haven't updated in quite a while because of my low-disk-space issue. Not sure if not updating got me excluded from the preview or not, but that's definitely my current version ;) When it's done upgrading I will update with the outcome :))

Comment: Insider Preview builds expire after a period of time. It appears the build expired on Dec 4th

Comment: That must be it, then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Preview builds are time limited.

> Certificate is not valid (ValidTime=2017-12-11T09:46:09.000000000Z Validity=[2017-03-23T18:24:49.000000000Z...2017-12-04T18:24:49.000000000Z]):

Suggests that your Insider Preview installation has expired.

> I tried changing the system date to a past date within the validity period and it worked, but of course that's a temporary solution (literally haha), as other stuff break down if I do so, and I'd like to know how to update the date in this eerie certificate.

Once this happens it means you have to reinstall Windows 10 or trick the system by changing the date and then install any updates.  I suggest you exit the Insider Preview channel update to the current RS3 build only after that go back to the Insider Preview channel.  You cannot update the certificate itself without updating Windows.  The file is signed which means any modification would invalidate the certificate

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows Insider Certificate has expired, you can get a new certificate by either reinstalling Windows or getting a new Windows Insider build.

According to [Updating from an expiring Insider Preview build](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/at-home/build-expiration) you can get a new Windows Insider Build without needing to reinstall Windows by following these steps:

> 1. Go to Settings > Update & Security > Windows Insider Program on your device.
> 2. Set it to the Dev Channel.
> 3. Go to Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update to check for the latest update, and update your device to the latest build available in the Dev Channel.